# getting contacts from gmail

Tags: asp.net, gmail

I am retrieving contacts from gmail using Google Data API. I have used below code:

```
string token = Request.QueryString["token"];
            RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings("myapp", token);
            rs.AutoPaging = true;
            List<string> lstEmails = new List<string>();
            try
            {
            rs.AutoPaging = true;
            ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);
            Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
            foreach (Contact e in f.Entries)
            {
                foreach (EMail email in e.Emails)
                {
                    lstEmails.Add(email.Address);
                }
            }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
```

But it reads only 25 gmail contacts only
and it throws the following error:

```
Execution Failed: {https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{email}/full?start-index=26&max-results=25}
```

but i want to get total contacts from gmail.

Comment: Did you check the Google Data API documentation? Perhaps you have to call `GetContacts()` in a different way, or multiple times? Or perhaps try setting `AutoPaging = true` *before* you call `GetContacts()`?

Comment: you mean RequestSettingsObject.autopaging=true. i did set it before calling GetContacts()

Comment: No you didn't. Look at your code. You call `GetContacts()`, and then on the next line you set `f.AutoPaging = true;`.

Comment: ya though i remove that one it showing same error. is there any way to  change max-results=25.

Comment: Remove what? I didn't say remove it, I said re-order it. And how am I supposed to know? Do you really want someone else to read the API documentation for you? **[Read it yourself!](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)**

Comment: when i am setting requestsettings with username and password its working fine but by using token it gives only 25 contacts. let me know   what i did wrong